# The castle/village relationship

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

I captured a 2nd castle. I collected awesome taxes for a week. Then I saw the associated village was granted to another lord! I checked my first castle, and noticed the associated village had no lord ( I expected myself! )

I mistakingly thought the village belonged to the castle's lord. Now that "my" village has been given away, my weekly income from the castle is 0.

1) Is there any way to get the village back for myself?

2) What use is a castle with no incomes, aside from strategic location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) I think you can ask the King for the village back. If possible, make sure your relations with as many other lords in your nation as possible are friendly to you (20+) and ask them to support you. Your renown will also factor in. If you become more renowned than the lord that acquired your village, it should be fairly easy.

2) You can store troops in your garrison, allowing you to recover very quickly from defeats. You can also get quests to rescue friendly prisoners, and hold feasts. See: http://mountandblade.wikia.com/wiki/Castles